# How to keep 1/10 of logs in filebeat + logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I use filebeat and logstash to monitor my access log.
now I want to keep 1 log for every 10 logs and drop other 9 logs, how should I write my configure file?

Comment: Do you want logstash to process only one log file out of every 10 log file?

Comment: yes, I know the config "drop{percentage => 90}" can achieve similar effect, but it can only reduce store pressure, I want to know if there is a similar config in filebeat ,so I can reduce the data translate pressure too.